# Binding IMap to XAML for Semantic Zoom

Tags: winrt-xaml, semantic-zoom

For Metro Apps, to implement Semantic Zoom using C++, is it possible to bind Windows::Foundation::Collection::IMap data to XAML? I have done using List in c#. I would like to do it using IMap for my C++ project.

Appreciate any good links for sample apps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can. You should use ObservableCollection instead of IList, of course. But (I think) you can do it without any change to the typical SemanticZoom implementation. The fact that your data is IMap data doesn't matter. Data is data.

Comment: Nixon - Could you please point me to some links for samples where Map is used for binding to XAML.? Thanks